# 3d animation in android

Tags: android

I am developing a android application which involves rotating the images in a horizontal way.
Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: What most people would do would be to look for sample apps, demos, tutorials etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3D flip example in ApiDemos:
In your Exclipse create a new Android project and select "Create project from existing sample". Choose target android version and then ApiDemos.
Run the program and go to Views>Animation>3D transition

There are many good examples there what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most convincing 3D flip animation I've seen is done here https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition.

A lot of the other tutorials and sample codes don't produce believable 3D flips. A simple rotation on the y-axis isn't what's done in iOS.

There is also a video here: http://youtu.be/52mXHqX9f3Y